# How do I edit the text in the button whenever it's clicked?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I made a button which makes 1 component invisible and another visible. Now I want to change the text in the button to show what component switches to whenever pressed. The code of the function in the button is:

```
  export class ToggleBarComponent implements OnInit {
    isDisplay = false;
    
    @Output() showHide: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
   
    toggleDisplay(){
     this.isDisplay = !this.isDisplay;
     this.showHide.emit(this.isDisplay);
     document.getElementById("Keyboard View").value="Touch View";
    }

    constructor() { }
   
    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
   
   }
```

The code in the html file:

```
<app-toggle-bar (showHide)=onShowHide($event)></app-toggle-bar>
        <div [hidden]="isDisplay" class="touchView">
          <app-touch-view></app-touch-view>
        </div>
        <div [hidden]="!isDisplay" class="keyboardView">
          <app-keyboard-view></app-keyboard-view>
        </div>
```

This is what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to modify the DOM to change the display text. You could use ternary operator using [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation#interpolation-) in the button label.

Try the following

Controller

```js
toggleDisplay() {
  this.isDisplay = !this.isDisplay;
  this.showHide.emit(this.isDisplay);
}
```

Template

```html
<button (click)="toggleDisplay()">
  {{ isDisplay ? 'Touch View' : 'Keyboard View' }}
</button>
```

---

Sidenote: Try not to access DOM directly using `document` in Angular. Instead you could use [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) with [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) or Angular [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2).